# Migrate site-packages/modules installed with pip from older to newer/latest version of python

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pythonpath, site-packages, linuxbrew

At first, I moved the python modules installed in the `/../python3.7/site-packages` to the new `/../python3.8/site-packages` directory manually.

To generalize the following question, I'm introducing the following nomenclature: The initial (lower) python-version will be represented by 3.x, the newer one by 3.y.
*In my case, x=7 and y=8.*

After the manual moving of the 3.x site-packages to the 3.y site-packages directory, I found that upon executing python scripts using the new python version 3.y certain errors occurred when calling specific modules like `numpy`, `scipy`, `matplotlib` etc.
The quite unelegant workaround which did it for me at last was simply `python -m pip uninstall packagename` followed by `python -m pip install packagename`, i.e. simply uninstall, then reinstall it. This way, the errors vanished.
Fortunately, I didn't have to do this with all of my more than 100 packages, it was rather necessary for just around 10.

Nevertheless, for the future I'd like to know how to migrate the packages more elegantly from the former to the current `python` version and update those automatically where it's needed.

---

System specifics:

- OS: `Linux Ubuntu 18.04 LTS`
- Python: `Python 3.8.3` (default, Jul  9 2020, 19:37:58)
  [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
  (maintained via `linuxbrew` / homebrew)
- Editor: `VS Code`

Comment: Dang.  I was hoping someone had answered this.  I now have the exact same question.

How did you get Pip to install newly downloaded stuff into 3.8/ instead of 3.7/?

Comment: The following discussion will be of interest for you as for where `pip` will install the packages: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980798/where-does-pip-install-its-packages In my case, pip pointed to the latest python site-package directory automatically. This is also related to my environment variables I'd set. Then, use `python -m pip install packagename` (preferred over `pip install packagename`).

Comment: @FrankYellin I've found a solution finally, see my answer below.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move all modules to new version of Python (from 3.6 to 3.7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51308683/how-to-move-all-modules-to-new-version-of-python-from-3-6-to-3-7)

Comment: The first answer does indeed answer my question, `pip freeze ... > requirements.txt` + `pip install -r requirements.txt` is the most elegant solution (I've updated my response below): https://stackoverflow.com/a/59608886/12298276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** The most elegant solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59608886/12298276):

---

I found a solution as a combination of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59608886/12298276) and changing the `PYTHONPATH` in two of my config-files:

```
/home/user/.bashrc 
/home/user/.bash_profile
```

Nomenclature: The initial (lower) *python-version* will be represented by *3.x*, the newer one by *3.y*.

---

**NOTE** on the necessity of previously modifying the `PYTHONPATH`:

In my case, as there were many `python`-versions installed in various ways and locations, it was needed to prepend the *target sitepackage directory* to every other one present in the entire `PYTHONPATH`, since only this way the extracted `python`-modules will be installed in the correct directory via `python -m pip install --user -r packages_python_3_x.txt`.

If on your system, the `PYTHONPATH` points directly to the site-packages of desire, i.e. they are in the first position of your entire PYTHONPATH, you wouldn't need to modify it.
Moreover, if you're working with virtual-environments (e.g. [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)) or other environment managers, you will be able to separate each site-packages associated to every virtual-environment automatically. Then, there should also be no need to modify the `PYTHONPATH`. By contrast, I didn't work with [virtual, local and global python environments](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/) and that's why it was necessary for me to prepend the site-package-directory of interest to the `PYTHONPATH`. Now, I'm working with virtual-environments for different projects, which I recommend to everyone.

---

**1.) Preparing the PYTHONPATH (if needed)**

Continuing with said config-files, therein, insert the following line:

```
PYTHONPATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/python3.x/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH"
```

In case there was a similar line pointing to the previous python-version directory, replace that with the most recent one in accordance with your situation (e.g. `3.7` with `3.8` in the directory path).

Moreover, if the system `python3`-path is prepended to the `PYTHONPATH`, comment that comment out in order to give your python distribution (be it `homebrew`, `anaconda`, or whatever you like) precedence.

```
# NOTE on the following commando: it is commented out on purpose (you could also delete it from the config-files, if you don't consider to use these site-packages again, but I kept it for playing safe)
#export PYTHONPATH="/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages:$PYTHONPATH"
```

In order to make changes take effect immediately, carry out the following commandos in your UNIX-terminal:

```
source /home/user/.bash_profile 
source /home/user/.bashrc
```

---

**2.) Extract currently installed modules and reinstall them with new version 3.y**

Finally, extract all `python`-packages installed to a textfile. In my case, this had been done with `pip`, so this would be:

```
python -m pip freeze --path /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/python3.x/site-packages > packages_python_3_x.txt
```

The textfile should contain lines like so:

```
absl-py==0.11.0
access==1.1.1
affine==2.3.0
aiohttp==3.7.2
aiohttp-cors==0.7.0
...
```

Finally, (re)install all these packages into the latest site-packages folder (here done using `pip`):

```
python -m pip install --user -r packages_python_3_x.txt
```

The package manager pip should choose the correct folder since you have updated the `PYTHONPATH` previously.
The new site-packages directory in this example should be `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/python3.y/site-packages`.